# modeling large documents in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a doubt about modeling collections in mongodb.

I'm working on a scientific application that generates a big matrix m x m, on the order of 13,000 columns and rows. You can see in the example below as a matrix :

```
|----------------|----------------|----------------|----------------|   
|                |    Attribute1  |   Attribute2   |   Attribute3   |
|----------------|----------------|----------------|----------------|
| **Attribute1** |       1        |   -0.398482    |    0.384382    |
| **Attribute2** |   -0.398482    |       1        |    -0.48327    |
| **Attribute3** |    0.384382    |   -0.48327     |        1       |
|----------------|----------------|----------------|----------------|
```

Unfortunately, the size of the array is too large, The array can not completely store in a single document. I would like to store the entire array in a single document because the document won't be updated, just insert and find_one commands will be applied the entire document, thus greatly facilitate the work.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

I thought of split the array by storing only one row at a time in each document. As the example below:

```
{ 
  {'row_number':1},
  {'attribute': 'attribute1'},
  {'values': [1,-0.398482,0.384382]}
}
```

Does it make sense, or have other better solutions than this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Since you refer to both rows and columns by attribute names, I think it might be an object of objects:

```
{
  Attribute1: {
    Attribute1: 1,
    Attribute2: -0.398482,
    Attribute3: 0.384382
  },
  Attribute2: {
    Attribute1: -0.398482,
    Attribute2: 1,
    Attribute3: -0.48327
  },
  Attribute3: {
    Attribute1: 0.384382,
    Attribute2: -0.48327,
    Attribute3: 1
  }
}
```

Each item in the collection would be an object of 13,000 properties, and each property would have 13,000 properties, resulting in crazy 169 million properties when flattened.

Your approach would increase the size by a constant, but I'm not sure it adds any value, since I can't see any case when you may refer to a vector by row number instead of attribute name.

---

You can also transpose this object if you think you'll more likely run operations against columns than against rows.

Comment: Hi Rishat.  is a good idea to create keys like your idea? What is difference between your idea and this example: {{attribute: 'attribute1', values: [{attribute: 'attribute1', value: -0.398482}]}}}?  about the amount of total data, Isn't it possible to store the entire data into a single document? Is it necessary to split the document?

Comment: Can you please explain why you _don't_ like object keys?